# Electromagnetic energy density in a nonlinear medium

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, non-linear-optics

The energy density associated with the electric field in a linear medium of permitivity  $ \epsilon $ is given as
$$
U = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon\left | E \right |^{2} 
$$
As Robert Boyd mentions in the first chapter of *Nonlinear Optics*, the electric field energy density for a nonlinear medium takes a different form from this equation. It has the usual linear term as above,also terms for each of the harmonic frequency.

The equation is lengthy, but assuming a third order non-linearity, it's proportional to
$$
\vec{E}^*\cdot\vec P,
$$
where $\vec{E}$ and $\vec P$ are the electric field and polarization vectors at third harmonic frequency respectively. If $\vec{E}$ and $\vec P$ were directly proportional to each other with a real number then this term would be real which is required for a quantity like energy density.

However, for situations like meta-materials, we know that this is not the case. In such situations, how do we go about using this equation to get the real energy density?